# CEFSharp,CEFGlue,ChromiumFX - What best for a plug-in type of WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, chromium-embedded, cefsharp, cefglue

For a plug-in type of WPF application, originally planned to use CEFSharp and I hit on a road block due to some known App domain issue. Let me get some expert openion before I take the next steps, what best fits for a plug-in type of WPF application?

Comment: It is absolutely opinion based question. CefSharp traditionally have ready to use control out of box. CefGlue has been crafted to access to raw CEF api from managed world. ChromiumFX relatively new, i'm never check it. Better ask on CEF forum with more detailed description what you want (with expectations). Otherwise everything can work. If you never used CEF before i currently recommend CefSharp.